# Equation of line from center of camera to plane in ThreeJS

Tags: javascript, three.js, threejs-editor, 3dcamera

I am working on a fork of threeJS editor and for a particular functionality, I need to get the world point where the center of camera is pointing at.

I believe that if I am able to get the equation of line from center of camera in the direction it's facing, then I can find the point at y=0 and I would eventually get the point on the plane.

I have tried the below code but it seems to also converge to the axis of plane i.e. (0,0,0)

```
let forward = new THREE.Vector3();
camera.getWorldDirection(forward)
let firstPoint = camera.position.clone();
let secondPoint = new THREE.Vector3();
secondPoint.addVectors(firstPoint, forward);
```

I have changed the code now to:

```
let camera = scene.getObjectByProperty("uuid", scene.userData.activeCamera);
let plane = new THREE.Plane( new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ), 0 );
let ray = new THREE.Ray();
let cameraPos = new THREE.Vector3();
let cameraDir = new THREE.Vector3();
camera.getWorldPosition(cameraPos);
camera.getWorldDirection(cameraDir);
ray.set(cameraPos, cameraDir);
let target = new THREE.Vector3();
ray.intersectPlane(plane, target);
this.controls.target = target;
```

and still the target that I get converges to zero and looks like below:

x: 1.7763568394002505e-15
y: 0
z: 8.881784197001252e-15

Below is an image which shows where the camera is exactly looking at in the editor:
[image: camera direction]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the following approach:

- Setup an instance of `THREE.Plane` representing the XZ-plane.
- Setup an instance of `THREE.Ray` based on the camera's position and look direction in world space.
- Use [Ray.intersectPlane()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Ray.intersectPlane) to find the intersection point of the ray and the plane.

Comment: I used your suggestion and update the code. Please have a look at the post again. @Mugen87

Comment: I've added your code to a live example and the result is as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/uzgb3vjs/.